# Changing wireless network password

Tags: wireless-networking, command-line, wireless-router

I have a cisco 1900 series router connected to a modem. I want to change the current wireless network password with which a user can access the network and connect to the internet. Is this supposed to be done via the CLI of the router? OR through the modem? and How?. Please I am quite confused about this.

Comment: What exact model is the router? Do you know if the router or the modem is supplying the WiFi (probably the router if you don't know)? Have you looked up the steps for changing the WiFi password for your router? Did they work?

Comment: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/cisco_configuration_professional_express/v2_7/guides/userguide/ccp_express_EndUser_Guide.html

Comment: @DarthAndroid The model of the router is Cisco 1941. I believe it's the router supplying the WiFi (is there a way to verify?). I haven't been able to find any steps yet. Do you have any links to share?

Answer (score -1):

To change a password on a Cisco 1941, follow the following steps (taken from [this source](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/3800-series-integrated-services-routers/112058-c1900-pwd-rec-00.html)):

> 1. Attach the router (via the console port) to your PC and start a terminal emulator with the following settings:
>
>    - 9600 baud rate
>    - No parity
>    - 8 data bits
>    - 1 stop bit
>    - No flow control
> 2. If you have successfully accessed the router, type show version into the prompt and write down the configuration register setting. (Ouput of an example of an entire password reset is below, done with a 2900 router but has the same procedure (source is same page))
> 3. Turn the router off and back on again.
> 4. Press Break on the terminal keyboard until you see that the router is in ROMMON mode.
> 5. Type "confreg 0x2142" and hit enter in the prompt that says `rommon 1>`.
> 6. Type "reset" and hit enter in the prompt that says `rommon 2>`.
> 7. Type "no" after each setup question and hit enter, or press Ctrl+C for each question to skip setup.
> 8. Type "enable", and hit enter, at the `Router>` prompt.
>
>    - You should now see the prompt `Router#`.
> 9. Type "configure memory" or (*exactly*) "copy startup-config running-config", then hit enter.
>
>    - This copies the NVRAM into the memory.
> 10. Now type "configure terminal" and hit enter.
>
>     - The terminal prompt should now be `hostname(config)#`.
> 11. Type "enable secret " (remember the space!) and type in your new password.
> 12. For every interface that you will use, put into up position by typing the name of the interface in the console, then hitting enter, then typing "no shutdown", and hitting enter. (if in doubt, look it up first)
>
>     - To see a list of available interfaces (specifically for finding their names), type "show ip interface brief" and hit enter.
> 13. Once you're finished putting up the interfaces you desire, type in "config-register "+the value you wrote down at the beginning (if you lost the value, you can safely put in 0x2102).
> 14. Type "end" and hit enter in the prompt after doing this.
>
>     - The prompt should now be `hostname#`.
> 15. Type in "write memory" or "copy running-config startup-config" to commit the changes.

It doesn't appear as though there is a way to change a password for your specific modem. I believe that the modem actually has no effect on the security of the broadcasting of your wifi, so this should do the trick.

(example mentioned above, below)

```
Router>enable
Password:
Password:
Password:
% Bad secrets

Router>show version
Cisco IOS Software, C2900 Software (C2900-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.0(1)M1, 
     RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2009 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Wed 02-Dec-09 15:23 by prod_rel_team

ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 15.0(1r)M1, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

c2921-CCP-1-xfr uptime is 2 weeks, 22 hours, 15 minutes
System returned to ROM by reload at 06:06:52 PCTime Mon Apr 2 1900
System restarted at 06:08:03 PCTime Mon Apr 2 1900
System image file is "flash:c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.150-1.M1.bin"
Last reload reason: Reload Command


This product contains cryptographic features and is subject to United
States and local country laws governing import, export, transfer and
use. Delivery of Cisco cryptographic products does not imply
third-party authority to import, export, distribute or use encryption.
Importers, exporters, distributors and users are responsible for
compliance with U.S. and local country laws. By using this product you
agree to comply with applicable laws and regulations. If you are unable
to comply with U.S. and local laws, return this product immediately.

A summary of U.S. laws governing Cisco cryptographic products may be found at:
http://www.cisco.com/wwl/export/crypto/tool/stqrg.html

If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to
export@cisco.com.

Cisco CISCO2921/K9 (revision 1.0) with 475136K/49152K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FHH1230P04Y
1 DSL controller
3 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
9 terminal lines
1 Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module
1 Cable Modem interface
1 cisco Integrated Service Engine-2(s)
   Cisco Foundation 2.2.1 in slot 1
DRAM configuration is 64 bits wide with parity enabled.
255K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
248472K bytes of ATA System CompactFlash 0 (Read/Write)
62720K bytes of ATA CompactFlash 1 (Read/Write)

Technology Package License Information for Module:'c2900'

----------------------------------------------------------------
Technology    Technology-package          Technology-package
              Current       Type          Next reboot
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ipbase        ipbasek9      Permanent     ipbasek9
security      securityk9    Permanent     securityk9
uc            uck9          Permanent     uck9
data          datak9        Permanent     datak9

Configuration register is 0x2102


Router>



!--- The router was just powercycled, and during bootup a
!--- break sequence was sent to the router after seeing the following message
!--- program load complete, entry point: 0x80008000, size: 0x6fdb4c.


!

rommon 1 > confreg 0x2142

You must reset or power cycle for new config to take effect

rommon 2 > reset

System Bootstrap, Version 15.0(1r)M1, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Copyright (c) 2009 by cisco Systems, Inc.
TAC:Home:SW:IOS:Specials for info
C2900 platform with 524288 Kbytes of main memory


program load complete, entry point: 0x80008000, size: 0x6fdb4c

Self decompressing the image : ###############################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
############################### [OK]


 Restricted Rights Legend

Use, duplication, or disclosure by the Government is
subject to restrictions as set forth in subparagraph
(c) of the Commercial Computer Software - Restricted
Rights clause at FAR sec. 52.227-19 and subparagraph
(c) (1) (ii) of the Rights in Technical Data and Computer
Software clause at DFARS sec. 252.227-7013.

 cisco Systems, Inc.
 170 West Tasman Drive
 San Jose, California 95134-1706

Cisco IOS Software, C2900 Software (C2900-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.0(1)M1,
     RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2009 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Wed 02-Dec-09 15:23 by prod_rel_team

Cisco CISCO2921/K9 (revision 1.0) with 475136K/49152K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FHH1230P04Y
1 DSL controller
3 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
9 terminal lines
1 Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module
1 Cable Modem interface
1 cisco Integrated Service Engine-2(s)
   Cisco Foundation 2.2.1 in slot 1
DRAM configuration is 64 bits wide with parity enabled.
255K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
248472K bytes of ATA System CompactFlash 0 (Read/Write)
62720K bytes of ATA CompactFlash 1 (Read/Write)


 --- System Configuration Dialog ---

Would you like to enter the initial configuration dialog? [yes/no]: n

Press RETURN to get started!

00:00:19: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface BRI0/0, changed state to up
00:00:19: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Ethernet0/0, changed state to up
00:00:19: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Ethernet0/1, changed state to up
00:00:19: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Serial0/0, changed state to down
00:00:19: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Serial0/1, changed state to down
00:00:20: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface BRI0/0, 
changed state to down
00:00:20: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Ethernet0/0,
 changed state to up
Router>
00:00:20: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Ethernet0/1, 
changed state to up
00:00:20: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial0/0, 
changed state to down
00:00:20: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial0/1, 
changed state to down
00:00:50: %SYS-5-RESTART: System restarted --
Cisco IOS Software, C2900 Software (C2900-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.0(1)M1,
     RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2009 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Wed 02-Dec-09 15:23 by prod_rel_team
00:00:50: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface BRI0/0, 
changed state to administratively down
00:00:52: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Ethernet0/0, 
changed state to administratively down
00:00:52: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Serial0/0, 
changed state to administratively down
00:00:52: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Ethernet0/1, 
changed state to administratively down
00:00:52: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Serial0/1, 
changed state to administratively down
00:00:53: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Ethernet0/0, 
changed state to down
00:00:53: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Ethernet0/1, 
changed state to down
Router>
Router>enable
Router#copy startup-config running-config
Destination filename [running-config]?
1324 bytes copied in 2.35 secs (662 bytes/sec)
Router#
00:01:24: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface BRI0/0:1, 
changed state to down
00:01:24: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface BRI0/0:2, 
changed state to down
Router#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line. End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#enable secret < password >
Router(config)#^Z
00:01:54: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
Router#show ip interface brief

Interface   IP-Address        OK?  Method     Status                   Protocol
Ethernet0/0 10.200.40.37      YES  TFTP       administratively down    down
Serial0/0   unassigned        YES  TFTP       administratively down    down
BRI0/0      193.251.121.157   YES  unset      administratively down    down
BRI0/0:1    unassigned        YES  unset      administratively down    down
BRI0/0:2    unassigned        YES  unset      administratively down    down
Ethernet0/1 unassigned        YES  TFTP       administratively down    down
Serial0/1   unassigned        YES  TFTP       administratively down    down
Loopback0   193.251.121.157   YES  TFTP       up                       up
Router#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line. End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#interface Ethernet0/0
Router(config-if)#no shutdown
Router(config-if)#
00:02:14: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Ethernet0/0, changed state to up
00:02:15: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Ethernet0/0, 
changed state to up
Router(config-if)#interface BRI0/0
Router(config-if)#no shutdown
Router(config-if)#
00:02:26: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface BRI0/0:1, changed state to down
00:02:26: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface BRI0/0:2, changed state to down
00:02:26: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface BRI0/0, changed state to up
00:02:115964116991: %ISDN-6-LAYER2UP: Layer 2 for Interface BR0/0, 
TEI 68 changed to up
Router(config-if)#exit
Router#
00:02:35: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
Router#copy running-config startup-config
Destination filename [startup-config]?
Building configuration...
[OK]
Router#show version
Cisco IOS Software, C2900 Software (C2900-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.0(1)M1,
     RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2009 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Wed 02-Dec-09 15:23 by prod_rel_team

ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 15.0(1r)M1, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

c2921-CCP-1-xfr uptime is 2 weeks, 22 hours, 15 minutes
System returned to ROM by reload at 06:06:52 PCTime Mon Apr 2 1900
System restarted at 06:08:03 PCTime Mon Apr 2 1900
System image file is "flash:c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.150-1.M1.bin"
Last reload reason: Reload Command

Cisco CISCO2921/K9 (revision 1.0) with 475136K/49152K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FHH1230P04Y
1 DSL controller
3 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
9 terminal lines
1 Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module
1 Cable Modem interface
1 cisco Integrated Service Engine-2(s)
   Cisco Foundation 2.2.1 in slot 1
DRAM configuration is 64 bits wide with parity enabled.
255K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
248472K bytes of ATA System CompactFlash 0 (Read/Write)
62720K bytes of ATA CompactFlash 1 (Read/Write)

Configuration register is 0x2102

Router#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line. End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#config-register 0x2102
Router(config)#^Z
00:03:20: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console

Router#show version
Cisco IOS Software, C2900 Software (C2900-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.0(1)M1,
     RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2009 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Wed 02-Dec-09 15:23 by prod_rel_team

ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 15.0(1r)M1, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

c2921-CCP-1-xfr uptime is 2 weeks, 22 hours, 15 minutes
System returned to ROM by reload at 06:06:52 PCTime Mon Apr 2 1900
System restarted at 06:08:03 PCTime Mon Apr 2 1900
System image file is "flash:c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.150-1.M1.bin"
Last reload reason: Reload Command

Cisco CISCO2921/K9 (revision 1.0) with 475136K/49152K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FHH1230P04Y
1 DSL controller
3 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
9 terminal lines
1 Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module
1 Cable Modem interface
1 cisco Integrated Service Engine-2(s)
   Cisco Foundation 2.2.1 in slot 1
DRAM configuration is 64 bits wide with parity enabled.
255K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
248472K bytes of ATA System CompactFlash 0 (Read/Write)
62720K bytes of ATA CompactFlash 1 (Read/Write)

Configuration register is 0x2142 (will be 0x2102 at next reload)

Router#
```

Comment: ... which router or modem does this apply to? What model?

Comment: Ah - I misunderstood the question, I believe. I answered assuming a Cisco modem, as this process only applies to such. Which modem _are_ you using, @ss_millionaire? (This method applies to all modern cisco routers.)

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE  I am using cisco 1941 router but the modem isn't a cisco modem. It's Huawei.

Comment: @ss_millionaire What Huawei modem model do you own, and which device's password do you currently use to connect to the internet? (as in, the router's or the modem's?)

Comment: The modem is Huawei HG8245A. I don't understand what you mean by what device password i use to connect to the internet. I think the password is independent of both devices because all three passwords are different or am i wrong?

Comment: Not wrong- just might help us figure out which device controls the password settings for the network. I'll get the steps for changing the password on both devices.